# Как изменять переменную в функции при каждой итерации цикла

Tags: java, массивы

```
for (int k = 0; k <= t - 2; k++) {
    double a, b;
    a = A.get(0) + (-gt(k + 1) + 640 + rt(0)); 
    b = A.get(k + 1) + rt(k + 1);
    if (a > b) {
        B.add(b);
    } else {
        B.add(a);
    }
}
```

Нужно чтобы при каждой итерации цикла в формулах `a` и `b` менялся первый элемент с `A.get(0)` и `A.get(k + 1)` на `B.get(0)` и `B.get(k + 1)`.

Comment: Суть вопроса непонятна. Если вам вместо `A.get` нужно использовать `B.get` - замените букву `A` на `B` и используйте. В чём вопрос/проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `A` и `B` наследуют общий интерфейс, можно объявить переменную этого общего типа и присваивать ей `A` и `B` по очереди.

```
Base c = null;
for (int k=0; k<=t-2; k++) {
    c = (k % 2 == 0) ? A : B;

    a=c.get(0)+(-gt(k+1)+640+rt(0)); 
    b=c.get(k+1)+rt(k+1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: А зачем объявлять `c` вне цикла?

Comment: Да без разницы. Это просто моя привычка объявлять многократно используемую переменную один раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean aFunc = true;
private boolean bFunc = true;

private double getFA(){
    double result;
    if (aFunc)
       result = A.get(0);
    else
       result = B.get(0)
    aFunc = !aFunc;
    return result;
}
```

Далее по аналогии пишем метод getFB(). Ну и ваш код изменится на

```
 a = getFA() + (-gt(k+1)+640+rt(0)); 
b = getFB() + rt(k+1);
```

Comment: Поправил, не до конца переименовал переменную)) bFunc будет использоваться в getFB() аналагично aFunc в getFB()

Comment: Я же написал - bFunc будет использоваться в getFB() Т.е. result = bFunc ? A.get(k+1) : B.get(k+1); bFunc = !bFunc;